# how to test password length on update of password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec2

When a new user is created they are given a password.

I want to test the case when the user updates or changes their password.

User.rb

```
 validates :password, :on => :create,
                :presence => true,
                :confirmation => true,
                :length => {:within => 6..12}

before_validation :make_password, :on => :create
```

In spec/models/user_spec.rb  I have the following:

describe "password validations" do
    before(:each) do
      @user = Factory(:user)
    end

```
it "should reject passwords that are too long" do
  too_long_password = "a" * 13
  @user.update_attributes(@attr.merge(:password => too_long_password, :password_confirmation => too_long_password)).should_not be_valid
end
```

end

Does not work.
Now how do I test for the update? 
Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the `:on => :create` clause from the validates. Removing this will activate the validation during create and update.

```
 validates :password,:presence => true,
                     :confirmation => true,
                     :length => {:within => 6..12}
```

You have not mentioned but you can also remove `:on => :create`, if it is needed in the before_validation too

Comment: I removed the :on => :create as per your instructions for the validates but need it for the before_validation as that is when I assign a password. What I was hoping to learn how to do was get how to write an rspec test for when I update the user info.